# File created by OpenEdge "OUTPUT" not available to UNIX for FTP

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

We are running OpenEdge 10.2b on an HP UNIX

We have been experiencing some strange behaviour regarding file availability between PROGRESS and UNIX. The situation is this (see full code below in update #2).

We are getting errors in the FTP stream where the CH-host-file is not found, even though the file was just created by program B. This error occurs intermittently, and it is always the last X number of files (for example, if there are fifteen files to be sent, and 4 files fail due to "host file not found" it will always be the last 4 in the list). It is usually 3-6 files that are not sent, and it happens about once every two weeks, but some weeks have multiple occurrences (this is a daily job).

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

For the time being, I have switched program B to use UNIX code, in case this is a file locking issue.

UPDATE:
The UNIX code to create the file has not helped, as the issue occurred again today

Is it possibly an order of execution issue? Can progress be running the OS-DELETE from Program A while the stream ftp in program C is still executing (that makes no sense to me, but I'm grasping here)

UPDATE #2:
FULL CODE
I'm getting edit error that won't let me post my code. So i posted it here: 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/49c84866d2f204f1cf05048abe3008ba
https://justpaste.it/1a59k

Comment: The `OS-APPEND` command might be failing. It doesn't return a Progress error. You have to check `OS-ERROR` to see what happened.

Comment: but why intermittently? and only for the last X # of files? And even if the append didn't work, the file should exist due to the OUTPUT STREAM in the first line, no? the data would be wrong, but the file should at least exist

Comment: This could not be related, and you could have ommitted this when you hid the unimportant part, but I don't see an OUTPUT STREM ST-ftp CLOSE in program C. If you're running A-B and B-C multiple times as you said, it could be possible you could be hitting some kind of open stream limit, thus making the last files fail. I don't know why this could be intermittent, though.

Comment: I assumed you have logged CH-to-file? It might contain some unexpected value?

Comment: @bupereira - i excluded that, but we send a "quit" and then close the stream

Comment: @Jensd - even if it contains an unexpected value, it shouldn't be returning an error of "File not found". It's not about the contents, the file just doesn't exist according to the FTP error log

Comment: I think you are going to need to post a more complete example.  Your existing psuedo code is probably glossing over an error that is behind the apparently missing file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some documentation on the subject, and doing a bit of testing, it seems the FTP stream only kicks off AFTER I close the OUTPUT. According to progress documentation, once I close the OUTPUT, the system pauses for 1 second and then continues running the program.

That would mean, in my case, the FTP would start and depending on connection time and upload speed, could still be in the process of uploading files while my Progress program was trying to delete them.

The solution in MY case was to move the delete into the FTP script, but for anyone who may read this, keep in mind the following:

1. Any UNIX (or OS) commands in a stream only get executed AFTER the stream is closed.
2. The OUTPUT STREAM runs entirely independent of your progress application (Progress pauses for 1 second after the OUTPUT CLOSE and then continues)

If is any chance of conflicting access/logic in the two streams, it may cause intermittent issues.